# Concat two strings, print and iterate

Tags: batch-file

How can I concat two strings to create directory path, print it and get all files ?

Here is my try:

```
set today=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%
set dir=\\room\c$\temp\here\201505\
set bbb = %dir%%today%-    

@echo %bbb%
```

In `bbb` variable I set `\\room\c$\temp\here\201505\20150520-` but when I print it I get `-1` as output.

Another question: how can I iterate all directories which starts with `20150520-` string ?

Comment: is this executed within some kind of  brackets?

Comment: what's the output of `echo %date%` ?

Comment: what is `c$` ?  Is it `$c ?

Comment: @ANjaNA assume dir is a UNC, and room is a server. "\\room\c$" gets me to "c:\" at room server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "today=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%"
rem why there was double percent at the end  ^
set "dir=\\room\c$\temp\here\201505\"
set "bbb=%dir%%today%-"
rem     ^- remove spaces around equal sign

@echo %bbb%
```

to iterate folders:

```
for /d  %%a in (20150520-*) do @echo %%~fa
```

Comment: Thanks! can you also refer to my second question about iteration ?

Comment: You should use `pushd "%dir%"` as most commands do not allow UNC paths

Comment: Hi, I'm writing: "
for /d %a in (%%day%*%) do 
(    
    echo 1

)"

In order to loop on all directories which start with %day% var, but I get this error : "20150521*) was unexpected at this time."
Can someone assist ?

Comment: @ohadinho try with `for /d %%a in (%day%*) do (@echo 1 )" `